# Cannot exceute Laravel-Blade files

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

I am new to PHP Frameworks, and I am currently using one of them called Laravel. I am using VSCode as the IDE. I am having some problems with the Blade template of Laravel, where when I try to run the blade templates in the localhost in the Browser or use the plugin LiveServer it doesn't work and I get the following images.
[image: When trying to launch chrome]

[image: When trying to open LiveServer]

In the first image is what I get when trying to launch chrome and in the second is when trying to open LiveServer.

Also, I have used the following code to route the blade file:

```
Route::view('app','app');

Auth::routes();
```

The blade file that I am trying to run is app.blade.php

I believe that I have done all the necessary configurations in VSCode, such as "Enable Blade" in Settings. Below is a copy of the code of my launch.json file, so the localhost is correct.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "type": "pwa-chrome",
           "request": "launch",
           "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
           "url": "http://localhost:8080",
           "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
       }
```

Also, these are the snippets that I have installed in VSCode:
**Laravel Snippets, Laravel Blade Snippets, Live Server, Live Sass Compiler, npm, PHP Debug, Sass.**

What do you think may be wrong?

Please do tell me if you need additional information.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Laravel/Blade, since you're getting can't connect to host in the first image, and a list of files in the second. The problem with the second is that the public directory should be your document root, not the project directory. There's an index.php file in there that drives the website.

Answer (score 0):

To serve up your laravel app, you need to execute `php artisan serve` inside your project via terminal ( you can use VSCode terminal ).

As in **web.php**, add routes like this :

```
Route::get('/home',[HomeController::CLASS,'index']);
```

and in your **HomeController** :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
       return view('index');
    }
}
```

after the project is served, you go to your browser and type it : http://localhost:8000/home

Comment: "_you should add routes like this_" ... or like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#view-routes). View routes are totally fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute php artisan serve to start the local development server.

[image]

Then in your browser type http://127.0.0.1:8000

You dont use live server, as it is only for front end technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Check this material out [Laravel 8 CRUD App, A simple guide](https://dev.to/kingsconsult/laravel-8-crud-bi9), this will expose you to Laravel routing, setting up, starting your server, running your blade files in the browser

Comment: Code in an answer would be nice, if that site you linked is down/unreachable, this answer is useless

Answer (score -1):

add routes like this

```
Route::get('your-url',[YOUR-CONTROLLER::CLASS,'your function']);
```

Closure function:

```
Route::get('your-url',function(){
  return 'yourview';
});
```

Comment: he is not pointing the route to index and even he did not added the controller or closure function so i just give a example

Comment: There's no need for a Controller or a Closure if you only want to show a view: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#view-routes